# ПО для терминалов оплаты

Tags: платежные-терминалы

Кто сталкивался с разработкой ПО для терминалов, как там устроена печать чеков? Насколько знаю, большинство работает в режиме киосков, то есть там должен быть какой-то API терминала, чтобы через JS дернуть? или как вообще?

Comment: Термопринтер поставляется с драйверами, SDK и прочей мишурой.

Если UI рисуется в браузере и вам нужно инициировать печать непосредственно из JS-кода, возможно подойдет принтер, который умеет OLE. Или можно написать модуль к браузеру. Или JS-код может вызывать что-то на серверной стороне (запущенной тут же в киоске), что отправит данные на печать.

В целом же, ваш вопрос слишком общий. Единственный достоверный ответ на него - "по-разному".

Answer (score 2):

Там 3 опции:

1. Windows, причем в кондовом варианте (были варианты даже Win95). Чаще всего Win 2000/XP, Win 7 редко;
2. Linux, в основном CentOS Linux;
3. IBM OS/2 - теперь уже редко (кстати многие банкоматы и кассовые терминалы до сих пор под OS/2).

А дальше все зависит от фантазии конкретного поставщика ПО/обертки. Гуглите. Спрашивайте у поставщиков киосков. Рынок узкий, публичных API скорее всего мало.